# How to get flash working in Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf

Tags: flash, 15.10

How do I get flash working for popular browsers like firefox, midori, etc. when the required packages aren't available through apt-get in Wily Werewolf 15.10? I've already added universe and multiverse in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, but still nothing?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, we'll utilize the command line to do the following:

1. Install flashplugin dependencies
2. Install flashplugin-installer
3. Install flashplugin-downloader
4. Rename the flash plugin
5. Install nspluginviewer
6. Install nspluginwrapper
7. Activate nspluginwrapper

In turn, doing this will:

- Install the flash plugin we need, for obvious reasons.
- Rename the flash plugin to make it work.
- Install NetScape Plugin Viewer (don't worry about netscape in the name, it's what we need), that the wrapper needs to function
- Install NetScape Plugin Wrapper (don't worry about netscape in the name, it's what we need), so we can make the flash plugin compatible.
- Activate the wrapper to get the plugin working for most popular browsers

**Step 1: Install flashplugin dependencies**

This is the easiest part, simply issue this command:

`apt-get install libpango1.0-0 libnss3 libnspr4 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls`

***If*** it fails and gives you a message about dependencies, issue this command:

`apt-get -f install`

**Steps 2 & 3: Install the flashplugin downloader/installer**

You'll need to get these yourself, I couldn't find them in the apt-get packages at time of this writing. In order to get them yourself, use launchpad.net. These commands will probably still work, but if significant time had passed since this writing and your reading of it, you may want to get the latest packages instead.

Another reason to get the latest yourself instead, is that these deb packages are for i386, if you have 64bit/PowerPC/etc you'll need the packages for them instead.

`wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/11.2.202.540ubuntu2/+build/8136297/+files/flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.540ubuntu2_i386.deb`

`wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/11.2.202.540ubuntu2/+build/8136297/+files/flashplugin-downloader_11.2.202.540ubuntu2_i386.deb`

Now do:

`dpkg -i flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.540ubuntu2_i386.deb`

`dpkg -i flashplugin-downloader_11.2.202.540ubuntu2_i386.deb`

*If it fails and gives you a message about dependencies, issue this command:* `apt-get -f install`

**Step 4: Rename flash plugin**

We need to do this, because it is written...

`sudo mv /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so`

**Steps 5 and 6: Install nspluginviewer and nspluginwrapper**

This is nice and easy, again though, these commands will probably still work, but if significant time had passed since this writing and your reading of it, you may want to get the latest packages instead.

Another reason to get the latest yourself instead, is that these deb packages are for i386, if you have 64bit/PowerPC/etc you'll need the packages for them instead.

`wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/136801009/nspluginviewer_1.4.4-0ubuntu5_i386.deb`

`wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/136801008/nspluginwrapper_1.4.4-0ubuntu5_i386.deb`

`dpkg -i nspluginviewer_1.4.4-0ubuntu5_i386.deb`

`dpkg -i nspluginwrapper_1.4.4-0ubuntu5_i386.deb`

**Step 7: Activate nspluginwrapper**

The final command:

nspluginwrapper -a -v -n -i

---

***You need to repeat Step 7 (and ONLY step 7) on each user's account you want to have access to flash. This only needs done 1 time on each account.***

A cheap way to do this from an account with sudo power is:

`sudo -u <username> nspluginwrapper -a -v -n -i`

Of course replace  with the user you want to have flash.